# Can I use poky/meta with my custom distro?

Tags: yocto

Hi I'm going to create my custom distro with the changes I need however I'm a little bit confused with poky/meta and meta-openembedded/meta-oe

First - as I understand poky/meta-poky is a layer that contains a reference distro: Poky, Poky-Tiny etc.
What's the poky/meta then?

I want e.g. to use util-linux.
I see that it is available in poky/meta/recipes-core/util-linux/util-linux_2.37.4.bb

but it is also available in openembedded/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-core/util-linux/util-linux_2.37.4.bb

I'm getting confused with this. Which one should I use?

Should I use poky/meta even if I'm going to create my custom distro or not?